# Wordpress h1 title PHP condition

Tags: php, wordpress

I've the following issue,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zwyj.png

Now as you can see in the image it should show recipes after "Cookies". Now the thing is sometimes the category has Recipes word. for this i'm trying to make php conditioning rule to check if recipes exist in the title then echo nothing else echo recipes.

```
                        else if( is_archive() ){
                        //echo __('Archive for ', 'recipe'). single_month_title(' ',false);
            echo single_cat_title('Amish '). single_month_title(' ',false). (' Recipes'); 
                    }
```

This the current code i've here. I need to make (' Recipes') show if it's not exist in the tile otherwise show.

Hopefully that's clear it up.

Comment: please specify the error ?

Answer (score 0):

[`single_month_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_month_title) is a **function**. You need to call it as a function. You also need to pass `false` in as the second parameter, so that the function `return`s the result (the same goes for `single_cat_title()`).

```
strpos(single_month_title(null, false), 'Recipes')
```

I'd do something like:

```
$recipes = strpos(single_month_title(null, false), 'Recipes') === false ? '' : ' Recipes';
echo single_cat_title('Amish ', false) . single_month_title(' ', false) . $recipes;
```

Comment: Can you rewrite it for me. 

if (strpos(single_month_title(null, false), 'Recipes') === false)
{
    echo single_cat_title('Amish ') . single_month_title(' ', false);
}
elseif (strpos(single_month_title(null, false), 'Recipes') == true)
{
    echo single_cat_title('Amish ') . single_month_title(' ', false) . (' Recipes');
}

Comment: it's not working... it should check from single_month_title if the title contain "Recipes" then do this or that

Comment: I added what I would do above.

Comment: Here's what i've

else if( is_archive() ){
      $recipes = strpos(single_month_title(null, false), 'Recipes') === false ? '' : ' Recipes';
      echo single_cat_title('Amish '). single_month_title(' ',false). $recipes; 
      }

Comment: You have an error somewhere else then. Turn on debugging and ask a new question if you can't resolve the error. There's nothing wrong with the code I've included above.